# Can't set multiple controls in one line with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm new in the world of Android development, and I'm trying to learn how to getting started from [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dn879698.aspx)
Now I've followed all steps until to put the `Zip Code` and the `Number` on the same line. I don't understand how can I manage this, if I drag and drop the `Number` control beside the `TextView` the `IDE` put the `Number` above the control or to the bottom. I don't know  how to explain correctly, anyway, this is an image:

[image]

and this is the `source` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ZipCodeEdit"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:textColor="#9933FF" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Zip Code: "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ZipCodeLabel"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

from the site should be like this:

[image]

what is wrong? Sorry if something is not clear, or if the category tag is wrong.

Comment: Your layout is also really inefficient-  there is 0 reason to ever have a relative layout inside a linear like that with no siblings.  I highly, highly suggest you don't use the drag and drop tools at all and learn how to do things from pure text-  the drag and drop tools are actually slower, don't get things right, and a bigger pain.  You'll need to use the text mode to get things right in the end anyway.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for the suggest. But as I said I'm new from this world and I'm trying to start with some example code provided by Microsoft.

Comment: that doesn't stop you from using the text based tools.  Really all the drag and drop tools will bring you is a world of pain. I've been doing Android since 2010, and I haven't touched the drag and drop stuff since that first year.  Also, any tutorial that doesn't give you the xml of the layouts is smelly to begin with.

Comment: @GabeSechan Well I'm agree with you, I'm using wpf for my c# application and I even wrote the xaml code manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make proper use of `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout` and `TableLayout` for the desired alignments.

> Here is your solution.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" >
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ZipCodeEdit"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:textColor="#9933FF" />
<TextView
    android:text="Zip Code: "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ZipCodeEdit"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ZipCodeLabel"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**What you were doing Wrong :**

You are trying to align EditText and TextView one beside another inside `RelativeLayout` but you've closed the relative layiut right where it started.
that makes the `EditText` and `TextView` the child view of the `LinearLayout(Vertical)`

As the text views are behaving as the children of Linear vertical layout there is no use of `RelativeLayout` hence aligning both views one below another.
One more thing when you fix that and put both the text view within `RelativeLayout` you have to align one view in relation with the another.

**In this case:**

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ZipCodeEdit"
```

Let me know if any problem.

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:minWidth="25px" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ZipCodeEdit"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#9933FF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ZipCodeLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ZipCodeEdit"
        android:text="Zip Code: "
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This seems working, thanks. So I guess that the controls isn't fill correctly in the `RelativeLayout` right?

Comment: where `RelativeLayout` you use end it with `/>` that not seems your all layout inside   `RelativeLayout` so make it  to `>` and End with `</RelativeLayout>` after Your view

Answer (score 0):

You are using a vertical `LinearLayout` as the parent layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Change `android:orientation="vertical"` to `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

You can also remove the `RelativeLayout` as it's not really being used(nothing inside it).

Comment: I'm just try to follow the instructions of the site. Anyway, if I change `vertical` to `horizontal` all controls disappear, why?

Comment: Remove the `RelativeLayout`, then change the `android:layout_width` of ZipCode TextView to be `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: If you want to go by the tutorial you are following, your layout parent needs to be a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`. It seems you just dragged a `RelativeLayout` into the designer, which is perfectly fine(for nested layouts), but doesn't seem to be what you want. Changing `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` also would need you to remove the `orientation` attribute as the `RelativeLayout` doesn't have an orientation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ZipCodeEdit"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:textColor="#9933FF" />
<TextView
    android:text="Zip Code: "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ZipCodeLabel"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This should fix your problem. I will explain if this works for you.